# PHP implementation of n:m relationship

Tags: php, mysql

As to implement a N:M relationship of tables `USERS` (PK: user_id which is auto increment INT) and `REQUESTS`(PK: request_id which is auto increment INT), I've created the intermediate table `USERS_GROUPS` (PKs: two FKs US_userid, US_requestid which coincide with the PKs of `USERS` and `REQUESTS`). When a user creates a new request I have to create a new record inside `REQUESTS`.

```
INSERT INTO REQUESTS (...) VALUES (...);
```

At the same time I want to create a new record inside `USERS_GROUPS` as to join `USERS_GROUPS` with `USERS` and `REQUESTS`. The value of the first FK pointed to `USERS` is known to me, however how may I find the value of the second FK pointed to the record I've just created?

In other words, I want to find the value of the field request_id of the  record I've just created. This seems a little bit confusing to me and I don't know how to implement it.

```
INSERT INTO USERS_GROUPS (US_userid,US_request_id) VALUES (...,?????);
```

This is my first serious db schema I've ever created and my first n:m relationship I have to manage. Is my point of view correct? If yes, I 'd appreciate your help in how to realise it. If not which is the right approach?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [last-insert-id](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/information-functions.html#function_last-insert-id) to retrieve the newly created id.

The library you use to connect to database usually has a function for it, such as [mysqli_insert_id](https://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.insert-id.php) or [PDO::lastInsertId](https://php.net/manual/en/pdo.lastinsertid.php).

*Sidenote:* Because you are performing multiple (independent) queries on the database it may be necessary to wrap it all in transaction.